# I can't get my URL rewrites to work AT ALL in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So basically I am trying to simply rewrite my URL and URL titles from *domain.com/city/?cityid=manhattan* to *domain.com/manhattan*
and make my URL title be shown in results as "Manhattan - domain.com"
Also, for my category+city pages, I want to change the URL from *domain.com/ads/?cityid=manhattan&ad_category=dogs* to *domain.com/manhattan/dogs* and my URL title to "Manhattan Dogs - domain.com"
I have been unsuccessful in doing a wordpress rewrite for months.
I am using the following codes in function.php and in htaccess.

**Function.php**

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
global $post;


add_rewrite_rule('^/([^/]*)/','index.php?  
cityid=$matches[1]&page=1205','top'); 
flush_rewrite_rules();




}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

**Htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cityid=$1&page=1205&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

How do I solve this functionality? It seems so difficult in wordpress.
Can anyone please help!

Comment: We might need a little more info to help out -- off the top of my head, what is cityid referring to? Is that a custom taxonomy of some sort? A custom post type? Also, have you added that query_var to WordPress using   add_filter( 'query_vars', 'function_name_goes_here') ?

Comment: City ID is referring to custom written cities (about 60 of them) and 4 categories in total, that advertisements are posted in. So basically the ads are posted in the city and category selected. The /Manhattan displays all ads in all categories, and /Manhattan/dogs only limits to a specific category in the city

Comment: What is the city though? Is that a WordPress custom post type, a taxonomy, or just something100%  completely custom that you've created?

Comment: /city is a page that displays all the cities. However, the cities themselves are custom taxonomies

Comment: Mixing Apache rewrites and WordPress internal rewrites is not usually a good idea. I would suggest using a custom, hierarchical taxonomy. If you don't know how to write one, [use a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/). However I'm not sure your ad system is using a custom post type, so it might not work for you.

Comment: No, the city ID is referring to a slug, a taxonomy basically. However, the city page is just a template page for the city the ads will be displayed in. The page is called city, and city ID refers to cities. I can avoid htaccess however I really need help with some coding.

Comment: Can someone please help me 

Comment: Custom taxonomies aren't usually displayed via a page. `page` is a specific post type in WordPress. You probably need your own custom post type. You're not getting help because your descriptions are unclear and you probably need to hire someone who can work with you on this.